# passing datagridview value to second form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

from few days i was searching the internet for a solution but no thing worked. so in my c# project i have tow datagradeviews first one which contains the database data in form1 and the second datagridview in form2 the datagridview has a checkbox now i need to transfer the checked rows values to the datagridview in form2 when button is clicked ,
in other words i need to transfer the checked value form datagridview in form1 to the second datagridview in form2 when the button is clicked , i have tried some methods but it did't worked

looking for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could add it to a dataset and then fill the DGV with the dataset on the second form. Or you could work with a database and essentially do the same thing.

You could also iterate through the DGV items by checking whether the row had the checked property set to 1. When it comes to checkboxes, 0 = false, 1 = true. So just pull all the values that have a 1.